# Jam scum after sealing

Tags: jam

I made strawberry jam and bottled and sealed using wax discs. I'm planning on selling the jam but scum has formed on top. If I open the jars they will have to be refrigerated and won't last. Is there anything I can do to save my jam without opening them?

Comment: Scum as in foam?

Answer (score 3):

Did you skim the scum during cooking?  Also, sealing with wax is no longer considered safe, especially if you plan to sell the jam.  It's possible that what you see is mold and not scum.

http://nchfp.uga.edu/how/can_01/prevent_spoilage.html

You might be able to save your batch, if it's not moldy if you throw away the wax, and reprocess in a water bath canner using lids and rings.